# How can I read the bits of a float as if it were an integer value?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

I want to read each bit sequentially, interpreting it as a big-endian integer value. I do *not* want to cast or converst the value; simply read the bit representation as-is, but interpreting it as if it were a 32-bit int.

```
Floating point representation of 49:
49.0  =  0 10000100 10001000000000000000000
 sign bit^ ^exp.    ^mantissa

Read as an int:
01000010010001000000000000000000 = 1111752704 (base 10)
```

Essentially, I'm looking to replicate the following C expression:

```
float y=49.00;
long i=*(long *) &y;
```

I tried simply compiling the C code above using godbolt and looking at the output, but the result wouldn't run in MARS.

Some things I've tried that hasn't worked:

```
    .data

floatlabel:   .float 2.5

# [...]

    l.s $f0,floatlabel
    sw $t0,0($f0)
```

```
    lwc1 $f1,floatlabel
    s.s $f1,floatlabel
    lw $t0,floatlabel
```

The first causes the compile error `"$f0": operand is of incorrect type`; the second `"2.5": operand is of incorrect type`,

Comment: store / reload always works (everything is just bits and bytes in asm; nothing special is needed to `lw` an FP bit pattern into an integer reg), or I think MIPS has instructions to move data between integer and FP registers without doing *conversion*, just copying the bit-pattern.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've added some more detail/examples of things that haven't worked.

Comment: The copy instructions `mtc1`, and `mfc1`, as well as the loads and stores (`lwc1`, `swc1`) do not change the bit pattern.  If you, however, want to convert float to int, you do that in the fp registers, then copy the value to a general (int) register.  If you want to convert int to float, you also do that in the fp registers, so copy the int into an fp register, then convert it to float.

Comment: You should not use a floating pointer register as the base reg in an addressing mode: you have `sw $t0,0($f0)`.  The integer registers are for addressing.

Comment: `mfc1` was exactly the instruction I was looking for! Thank you very much for your insight. I wish I could mark this an an accepted answer.

Comment: Your C expression takes the address and dereferences it.  This cancel out so in assembly we would simply do `long i =  y;` without any value conversions.  FYI, I don't get an error in MARS doing `lw` on a float label.

Comment: @BigfootLives: You can write up an answer to your own question (including in the case where someone gives a short answer in comments which you can cite.)  Although if you're still making MIPS mistakes like `0($f0)`, make sure to test any code you put in an answer to make sure you got it right!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much to @ErikEidt for his answer: The `mtc1` and `mfc1` instructions are what I was looking for, as they move values to and from the floating point coprocessor without changing the bit pattern. To read a single-precision FP value as if it were an int, I did the following:

```
mtc1 $t0, $f0
cvt.s.w $f0, $f0  # changes the bit pattern 
                  # from word to single-precision
mfc1 $t0, $f0
```